# Error (36) When Trying to Connect to AWS MySQL instance through R

Tags: mysql, r, amazon-web-services

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database instance I created on AWS through R.

Here is the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(pool)
library(RMySQL)



#install.packages(c("DBI", "RSQLite", "dbplyr"))


host= 'ufc-db0.c7mdwtbfqqph.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com'
port=3306
dbname= 'ufc-db0'
user= 'admin'
password = ....


my_db = dbPool(RMySQL::MySQL(),
                #dbname=dbname,
                host=host,
                port=port,
                user=user,
                password=password)


Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ufc-db0.c7mdwtbfqqph.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (36)
```

Here are my configurations:
[Instance Configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xt3ie.png)

I've made the instance publicly accessible and I've tried removing dbname from the arguments. I even triple checked my credentials.

I also initially tried using dbConnect but then tried using dbPool.

Comment: Can you check the security group and update it?